# error in computing the generalized eigenvalues in R with geigen package

Tags: r, matlab, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I'm using the R package geigen to solve the generalized eigenvalue problem A*V = lambda*B*V.
This is the code:

```
geigen(Gamma_chi_0, diag(diag(Gamma_xi_0)),symmetric=TRUE, only.values=FALSE) #GENERALIZED EIGENVALUE PROBLEM
```

Where:

```
Gamma_chi_0
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
[1,]  1.02346 -0.50204  0.41122 -0.73066  0.00072
[2,] -0.50204  0.96712 -0.33526  0.51774 -0.37708
[3,]  0.41122 -0.33526  1.05086  0.09798  0.09274
[4,] -0.73066  0.51774  0.09798  0.99780 -0.51596
[5,]  0.00072 -0.37708  0.09274 -0.51596  1.03354
```

and

```
diag(diag(Gamma_xi_0))
     [,1]   [,2]    [,3]   [,4]    [,5]
[1,] -0.0234 0.0000  0.0000 0.0000  0.0000
[2,]  0.0000 0.0329  0.0000 0.0000  0.0000
[3,]  0.0000 0.0000 -0.0509 0.0000  0.0000
[4,]  0.0000 0.0000  0.0000 0.0022  0.0000
[5,]  0.0000 0.0000  0.0000 0.0000 -0.0335
```

But I get this error:

```
 > geigen(Gamma_chi_0, diag(diag(Gamma_xi_0)), only.values=FALSE) 

 Error in .sygv_Lapackerror(z$info, n) : 
 Leading minor of order 1 of B is not positive definite
```

In matlab, using the same two matrices, it works:

```
opt.disp = 0;
[P, D] = eigs(Gamma_chi_0, diag(diag(Gamma_xi_0)),r,'LM',opt);              
% compute first r generalized eigenvectors and eigenvalues
```

For example I get the following eigenvalues matrix

```
D =

  427.8208         0
         0  -38.6419
```

Of course in matlab I just computed the first r=2, in R i want all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors (n=5), and then i subset the first 2.

Can someone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`geigen` has detected a symmetric matrix for `Gamma_chi_0`. Then Lapack encounters an error and cannot continue. Specify `symmetric=FALSE` in the call of `geigen`. The manual describes what argument `symmetric` does. Do this

```
geigen(Gamma_chi_0, B, symmetric=FALSE, only.values=FALSE)
```

The result is (on my computer)

```
$values
[1]  4.312749e+02 -3.869203e+01 -2.328465e+01  1.706288e-05  1.840783e+01

$vectors
             [,1]       [,2]      [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
[1,] -0.067535068  1.0000000 0.2249715 -0.89744514  0.05194799
[2,] -0.035746438  0.1094176 0.3273440  0.03714518  1.00000000
[3,]  0.005083806  0.3782606 0.8588086  0.50306323  0.17858115
[4,] -1.000000000  0.2986963 0.4067701 -1.00000000 -0.48314183
[5,] -0.034226056 -0.6075727 1.0000000 -0.53017872  0.06738515

$alpha
[1]  1.365959e+00 -1.152686e+00 -9.202769e-01  4.352770e-07  5.588102e-01

$beta
[1] 0.003167259 0.029791306 0.039522893 0.025510167 0.030357208
```

This is quite close to what you show for Matlab. I know nothing about Matlab so I cannot help you with that.

**Addendum**

Matlab seems to use similar methods as `geigen` when the matrices used are determined to be symmetric or not. Your matrix `Gamma_chi_0` may not be exactly symmetric.  See this [documentation for argument 'algorithm' of eig](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html).

**More addendum**

In actual fact your matrix `B` is not positive definite. Try the function `chol` of base R. And you'll get the same error message. In this case you have to force `geigen` to use the general algorithm.

Comment: thanks for your answer, actually Gamma_chi_0 is symmetric, so I think the problem is that B is not positive definite. Can you explain me what does it mean to force geigen to use the general algo? you mean to write symmetric=false?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. `B` is not positive definite as I mentioned in **More addendum**. However it is symmetric and that is what the code tests for; maybe a stricter test in `geigen` is required. The general algorithm uses the QZ, Schur decomposition. And that does  not require positive definite matrices. See the manual of  `geigen`.